# Create a .csv file and then tell the printer to print the file

Tags: wpf, csv, printing

So I have a program where I am able to successfully create a .csv file with my data.
I now have to somehow print that file.

I looked up a lot of resources about printing in WPF but they are all so complex and I can't make head and tails of what the barebones printing statements are.

Is there a way for me to just tell the application to take a specific filepath and then print the contents of the file as it would be if I manually went and opened the .csv file and hit print?

**Edit:**

Alternatively, I have been told I could do this; take a screenshot of my screen (printscreen) and then tell the printer to print the image from clipboard.  But this has to be all done when a button called 'Print' is pressed.

Update:

For my first query, what I'm doing now is opening the .csv file when I press the print button and then using excel's print function to get my printout and its working.

But I would like to have it work with what is seen directly in the application with the printscreen method.

Comment: How do you want it printed? Via Excel?

Comment: There are many applications that already print CSV files; why do none of them work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "[Verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx)" property of [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) with [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) to open and print the CSV file with the default program associated with CSV files.  You need to set the "Verb" to "**print**".

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\myfile.csv";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
                myProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a verb I can use to expand the first column before the print? It is printing now but the first column is of a set width and the whole name is not readable in printout.

Comment: Common verbs include "edit", "find", "open", and "print".  I'm not aware of any verbs that would expand the first column.